# multiple sections in a csv row

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file formatted

```
<F,Bird,20,10/> < A,Fish,5,11,2/>
```

I was wondering how to read in those values separately.

Would I have to get the whole line to an array?

I have thought of doing `line.split("/>")` but then the first data would have `<` in them which I don't want.

If I on the other hand just seperate it using `line.split(",")` and then assign each values accordingly the values in the middle would merge so that does not work neither.

Is there a way to separate the string first without the `<>/` symbols?

Comment: How do you want to use these values?

Comment: i want to store them in classes aquatic and flying @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your input string using the lookbehind `?<=/>`:

```
String input = "<F,Bird,20,10/> < A,Fish,5,11,2/>";
input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=/>)");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part.replaceAll("[<>/]", ""));
}
```

Note that I removed all spaces from your string to make splitting cleaner.  We could still try to split with arbitrary whitespace present, but it would be more work.  From this point, you can easily access the CSV data contained within each tag.

**Output:**

```
F,Bird,20,10
A,Fish,5,11,2
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: so the output still has <>/ ? if i was to store just F without< how would i do that?

Comment: Yes, but you can do whatever you want at this point.  For example, you could remove the brackets.

Comment: im not quite sure how to use replaceAll, if i do part = part.repplaceAll("<>/", "") would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use several delimiters in split regexp, like this:

```
String line = "<F,Bird,20,10/> < A,Fish,5,11,2/>";
String[] lines = line.split("<|/> <|/>");
for (String item: lines) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Output (with all your spaces):

```
F,Bird,20,10
 A,Fish,5,11,2
```